# how to load HTML pages, from a location different from root, on the same server?

Tags: html, osx-server

I am making my first web site with OSX; this is an internal website for my company.

When the server start, I load pages from a different location, from the one that OSX server used to create my template site (because I do redirects that go on the same IP address, so the pages of the redirect obscure the ones from OSX server). These pages are served by a product called Buildbot (a CI server).

Now, I load the main page from the python directory on my computer, and I would like to avoid to get all the pages for the server there, to not mix them up with the buildbot pages; so I am trying to use the directory that OSX server created for me.

The issue thou, is that I do not know how to link pages...HTML is something that I forgot with time; but I remember that each site starts from a root directory, so the computer is protected by outsiders that may try to force it.

Now, I assume that my root is where the start page is loaded from (in my case is /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildbot-0.8.8-py2.7.egg/buildbot/status/web/templates/), so if I use an href to link to another page, I can just access to this tree.

Which means that my website should be in a folder in this path? I can't seem to access the site where OSX server created the website resource (which in my case is Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/mySite/).

Has been so long since when I used HTML, so I am quite rusty on the topic, and would appreciate a lot any kind of hint. The site will not be available outside our internal network, so I simply need to link pages and resources scattered on my server HD, and put them on web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understand:
Let's say your web root is /root, but you want to have a href to an html file in /dog, for example. Is this correct?

Assuming so, you cannot link an HTML file that is not in the web root, as the browser needs to be able to access it. If you were using a server-side programming language you could do this, but not with HTML.

Comment: Yes, it is a similar case as you described; altho I have no idea where the root is...I was expecting to see my root on the location where OSX server create the server folder, but it is not true. So there is no way to create a HTML link to a file that is on my computer, but not in the root?

Comment: If you're wanting to find the root, create an html in one directory saying "1," and another html document in the other saying "2." After doing this, goto http://whatever/filename.html and you'll be able to determine the true root. All **public** files must be in the root directory as well.

Comment: Did as you suggested; it is loading the file that is in the python directory. Now when I add a href, I would expect that it would look in the same dir and load the html page that I specify, but instead, it says that cannot find the page. The url, in case of my page (called test.html) looks like my site.com/test.html, but nothing is displayed. Makes no sense. I wish there was a sort of debugger to know what is going on with the requests (I know how to use charles proxy, but is not a problem with requests but of what happens internally after getting the request).

Comment: Install Apache and remove the other stuff (It might be called httpd) and you'd probably be able to find a tutorial on running Buildbot in Apache/httpd, although I'm not sure where to find one.